# Syntax error in subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting a #1064 error from this code I am trying to use a subquery within the values command  I am new to mySQL and cannot spot the mistake.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable(myid INT,points INT)
INSERT INTO TempTable
values(1,
points
(
 SELECT player.team, COUNT( * ) AS count
 FROM playerpoints
 JOIN player ON playerpoints.PlayerID = player.PlayerID
 WHERE player.team = 'ManU'
 AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM playerpoints.date ) <07
 GROUP BY player.team
));

INSERT INTO TempTable
values(2,
points
(
  SELECT player.team, COUNT( * ) AS count2
  FROM playerpoints
  JOIN player ON playerpoints.PlayerID = player.PlayerID
  WHERE player.team = 'ManU'
  AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM playerpoints.date ) >07
 GROUP BY player.team
));

DROP TABLE TempTable;
```

Comment: does your subquery return anything on its own?

Comment: You need a comma after `points`.  Your subquery can only return *one* row.  I'm not even sure you can use a subquery in an `INSERT` statement in the first place.

Comment: When posting examples, it is best to use the shortest and simplest example that produces the error. I'm guessing you still get the error if you leave out the 2nd INSERT statement.

Comment: Try taking out the word 'points'. It's irrelevant. You don't put column names in the VALUES() part. You want `INSERT INTO temptable VALUES(value1, value2)`. You are trying to do: `INSERT INTO temptable VALUES(value1, columnName(selectStatement)`. Just put in the select statement.

Comment: Wait a minute.  `TempTable` has 2 fields, right?  What *exactly* are you trying to insert?  Why do you have `1, points` and then a subquery?  What row(s) are you trying to insert?

Answer (score 1):

The construct you want to use is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.  You don't use a subquery (or the `VALUES` keyword).

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (myid, points)
SELECT player.team, COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM playerpoints
JOIN player ON playerpoints.PlayerID = player.PlayerID
WHERE player.team = 'ManU'
AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM playerpoints.date ) <07
GROUP BY player.team;
```

Basically, you want the `SELECT` to return the row(s) you're inserting (in the correct order).

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

No semicolon at the end of the first line. Also the `INSERT` syntax can be cleaned up a bit. Finally, the `GROUP BY` clause is not needed. Try this:

Try this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable(myid INT,points INT);

INSERT INTO TempTable
values(1, (
  SELECT COUNT( * )
  FROM playerpoints
  JOIN player ON playerpoints.PlayerID = player.PlayerID
  WHERE player.team = 'ManU'
  AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM playerpoints.date ) <07
));

INSERT INTO TempTable
values(2, (
  SELECT COUNT( * )
  FROM playerpoints
  JOIN player ON playerpoints.PlayerID = player.PlayerID
  WHERE player.team = 'ManU'
  AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM playerpoints.date ) >07
));

...

DROP TABLE TempTable;
```

This assumes that `playerpoints` records one point per entry. Otherwise you'll need something like `SELECT SUM(playerpoints.points`) instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)`.